# Replace filename with fingerprinted version using Grunt

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

assets.json maps the filenames:

```
{
 "css\\global.css": "css\\global.a4b054fc.css",
 "js\\js-common.js": "js\\js-common.d41d8cd9.js",
 "js\\js-libs.js": "js\\js-libs.c3d17a06.js",
 "js\\js-trace.js": "js\\js-trace.60465814.js",
 "templates\\error.hbs": "templates\\error.6d003395.hbs"
}
```

During the build process (Grunt) I need to match the original file names (within a html file) and replace them with the fingerprinted version.

I've looked at a few packages however none seem to do what I'm looking for, any ideas?

Comment: How about the `patterns.json` method in [Grunt replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace#patternsjson)? Seems right up your street.

Comment: You can also use grunt-filerev + grunt-usemin

Comment: Grunt replace looks like it could do the job however it appears the patterns.json requires the JSON to be specified within the Gruntfile, I need it to be imported from an external file.

Answer (score 0):

Refer npm grunt-rekai which does what you need and if you would need more than available feature. You can add own tak after that using grunt-exec